# Cannot assign value of type 'ListViewController.Album' to type 'Album'

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

Here is the line I got the mistake: `viewController.album = album`

I'm learning to do an album list which is almost same as a to do list by following a youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfupg-OeY94

The time which I got problem is about 47:55 in the video.

I don't know why this error happens and I don't know how to search that on website to figure it out.
As I use Command + right click, it will show the album at last is with the album in

```
let album = albums[indexPath.row]
```

And Here is my ViewController Code:

```
class ListViewController: UITableViewController {
     var albums: [Album] = []
    
    struct Album {
        let albumName: String
        let artistName: String
        let year: String
        let record: String
        let list: String
        }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     
    }

    /* data Source  */
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return albums.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "albumCell", for: indexPath)
        
        let album = albums[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = album.albumName
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = album.artistName
        
        return cell
    }
    
    //Navigation
    
    
    // unwind segue
    @IBAction func unwindToAlbumList(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if let viewController = segue.source as? EntryViewController {
        guard let albumName = viewController.albumNameTextField.text, let artistName = viewController.artistNameTextField.text, let year = viewController.yearTextField.text, let record = viewController.recordtextField.text, let list = viewController.listTextField.text else { return }
        let albumNew = Album(albumName: albumName, artistName: artistName, year: year, record: record, list: list)
        albums.append(albumNew)
        tableView.reloadData()
        } else if let viewController = segue.source as? DetailViewController {
            if viewController.isDeleted {
                guard let indexPath: IndexPath = viewController.indexPath else { return }
                albums.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "albumDetailSegue" {
            guard let navViewController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController else { return }
            guard let viewController = segue.destination as? DetailViewController else { return }
            guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return }
            let album = albums[indexPath.row]
            viewController.album = album
            viewController.indexPath = indexPath
            
           
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: what is error ?

Comment: I do not see your DetailViewController, which would be a helpful addition. My guess is that you redefined the struct Album there. If you did this, it is not actually the same struct, namely `ListViewController.Album` but `DetailViewController.Album`. It is also generally nicer to keep model classes (like your Album) separate. Move the `Album` struct to a separate file and out of the ListViewController.